# @Transactional not working when i throw exception on next line

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, spring-boot

I don't understand the below behavior:

I have a method:

```
@Transactional
public void processRejection(final Path path) {

    try {

        //some code here

    } catch (final Exception e) {
         this.handleException(e));
    }
 }
```

which calls the below which does a `saves` an entity which doesn't yet exists in the database:

```
void handleException(final Throwable e) {

    this.filesMonitoringJpaManager.save(someEntityHere);

    throw new Exception(...)
}
```

Now the strange is when I **comment** the `throw new Exception(...)` the `save` works, but when I **uncomment** `throw new Exception(...)` then the `save` doesn't work and I have no clue why?

What strange behavior is that from JPA or Hibernate? Is it something about Java Exception mechanism which I don't understand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Transactional` is meant to roll back when something goes wrong (an exception is thrown). You're saving an entity in the `catch` block, but you're rethrowing an exception causing the transactional method to roll back.

But you can specify an exception, that will not cause rollback:

```
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = {MyException.class})
public void processRejection(final Path path) {

    try {
        //somecode here whatever
    } catch (final Exception e) {
         this.handleException(e));
    }
 }

void handleException(final Throwable e) {
    this.filesMonitoringJpaManager.save(someEntityHere);
    throw new MyException(...)
}
```

This works for `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`. If you're using `javax.transaction.Transactional`, then you can achieve it by using `dontRollbackOn` property.

Comment: @GOXR3PLUS I'm rolling back your changes. `noRollbackFor` is for `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`

Comment: Gotch you :) Thank you so much.

Comment: If MyException is a business logic exception, you should just use checked exceptions. For checked exceptions, there is no rollback by default.