# @Transactional rollback everything except one save on the database

Tags: java, spring, database, hibernate, spring-boot

Following my previous question which was nicely answered => [@Transactional not working when i throw exception on next line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60995945/transactional-not-working-when-i-throw-exception-on-next-line)

I have this question now :

I have a method:

```
@Transactional
public void processFile(final Path path) {

    try {

        //code that manipulates database adding entries

    } catch (final Exception e) {
         this.handleException(e));
    }
 }
```

which calls the below appending the `fileName that failed` as an entry on the database table (**monitoring**):

```
void handleException(final Throwable e) {

    //Save the name of the file that failed to be processed
    this.filesMonitoringJpaManager.save(newEntryFileName);

    throw new Exception(...)
}
```

---

So the method **processFile** is doing various database changes that i want to rollback when any error occurs . Though method **handleException** is saving to table **monitoring**  the fileName is failed to be processed.

---

So :

How can i rollback the whole transaction in case of **Exception** but still do that **save/update** `this.filesMonitoringJpaManager.save(newEntryFileName);` on the database because i need it ?

Comment: @Andronicus Have a look please :)

Comment: @AlexLiesenfeld Have a look please :)

Comment: You can only store things inside a transaction, so this won't work. The only solution would be to start a new transaction to store that piece of data.

Comment: @M.Deinum So i have to change the architecture , what you reccomend :) ? I break into two methods ? I need it to both return the error because it appears on the User UI and both do the save for that failed file in database :)